# what is sync_extras_upload used for?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

Within the ContentResolver class, there are several constants that are used for syncadpaters. I want to know what the constant SYNC_EXTRAS_UPLOAD is used for?

Answer (score 1):

If you check in the SyncManager.java file you find this comment:

> If the ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_UPLOAD boolean in extras is
>        * true then initiate a sync that just checks for local changes to send
>        * to the server, otherwise initiate a sync that first gets any
>        * changes from the server before sending local changes back to
>        * the server.

and from the same file this is the implementation of the `scheduleLocalSync` API

```
public void scheduleLocalSync(Account account, String authority) {
    final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_UPLOAD, true);
    scheduleSync(account, authority, extras, LOCAL_SYNC_DELAY,
            false /* onlyThoseWithUnkownSyncableState */);
}
```

The method `onPerformSync`of your syncadapter receives those extras as one of the paramters

Comment: I tried putting this extra in a requestSync call but never get a sync trigger or this extra

Comment: You called requestSync and you did not get the onPerformSync triggered? That's weird because I did it several times. Or you meant that you get a call to onPerformSync but there were no extras?

Comment: Nope, onPerformSync was never triggered

Comment: So you have something wrong somewhere else it does not have to do with SYNC_EXTRAS_UPLOAD. Have you added your Account? Have you passed the right Account?

Comment: BTW why aren't you calling scheduleLocalSync directly?

Comment: Because that method is not public or reachable, the SyncManager class is not available